# Javascript click function on table cell on Android web browser not working

Tags: javascript, android, onclick

My code works well on desktop, but not on the Android platform.
I know problem click function on Android device, but not have enough experience to make code work for desktop and android platform:

```
var myTableArray = [];
$("table#sound_list_table tr").each(function() {
    var arrayOfThisRow = [];
    var tableData = $(this).find('td');
 if (tableData.length > 0) {
    tableData.each(function() { arrayOfThisRow.push($(this).text()); });
    myTableArray.push(arrayOfThisRow);
    }
});   

var PI = {  
onReady: function(){
    $('#sound_list_table td').click(function() {
    var column_num = parseInt( $(this).index() ) + 1;
var row_num = parseInt( $(this).parent().index() )+1;
var res = myTableArray[row_num-1][0];
if ((column_num == 1)||(column_num == 2))
    {
        if (confirm('Are you sure play sound res ?')) 
        {
                    $.ajax({
        url: 'playsound.php',
        type: 'get', //send it through get method
        data: { 'res': res }
        //success: function(response) { },
        //error: function(xhr) {  }
        });
                return true;
            } 
    else {  return false;  }
        }});
}
};$(document).ready( PI.onReady );
```